# Making the Bullet Stay in the Same Space

Tags: python, pygame

I have a spaceship that shoots bullets. The bullet follows the ship so it stays hidden. The only problem is that when I shoot the bullet it still follows the ship. The way it shoots is as follows:

(outsde the 'if run' loop)

b_vel = 0

(inside the 'if run' loop)

```
 b_y -= b_vel
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        b_vel = 15
```

How would I use this to make the bullet stay on the same x axis after it is fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making your gaming system do too much work.  Do not create the bullet sprite at all until you shoot.  Then simply send it on the required trajectory.  Having it as a hidden shadow on board the ship is extra work.  Just keep a counter for the amount of bullets the ship carries; don't make objects until they affect the game play.

Comment: This is definitely better advice than my answer for overall game design. It also makes it much easier to have more than one bullet at the same time.

Comment: @Prune how do I just send it on that trajectory?

Comment: You search on line for "Pygame move sprite".  You create the bullet as a sprite and alter the x-y coordinates per your game needs.  Use the same logic you use for moving your ship?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add all of your code here so I am not sure that this would work, but I would add an extra variable that just keeps track of whether or not the bullet has been fired, or maybe even just check the b_vel variable. And when you are updating the b_x to make it follow the ship, just only do that if the b_vel isn't set.

Something like this.

```
if b_vel == 0:
    b_x = ship_x
```

So that if the bullet has velocity the x value is no longer bound to the ship.